# Root a phone using Quadrooter

Tags: root-access, motorola-moto-e

According to [zdnet](http://www.zdnet.com/article/quadrooter-security-flaws-affect-over-900-million-android-phones/), the quadrooter vulnerability allows the attacker to

> ...gain root access, which gives the attacker full access to an affected Android device...

Does this mean that some qcom phones will now have a chance to obtain root?

I'm asking this because I want to root my moto e which is locked thanks to verizon.

Answer (score 4):

Quadrooter refers to a set of vulnerabilities , which are explained in the question here [What is QuadRooter? Are 900 million Android devices vulnerable?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/154279/131553)

These vulnerabilities *may* be translated into rooting techniques in due course, if security upgrades don't fix them (even if upgraded, it may not reach all devices for various reasons)

To answer your question, it may be possible, but at this point of time, nothing can be said with certainty.

Comment: So technically it's possible, but no one out there has tested it yet...?

Comment: Yes, technically possible if one knows how to do it